# lookup for a known key-value pair in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I have an integer field in the bean I use in my JSF application.
The integer field is showing the status of the process and it can be 0, 1 or 2.
What I'd like to do is either automatically map this value to the corresponding String representation (0- not processed yet, 1- being processed ...etc) or do this in a hard-coded way using jsf. I don't prefer to handle it in another way because the main jsf bean I use contains several hibernate models and it'll get complicated if I opt another way.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for [i18n.](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/102-implement-internationalization-and-localizati.html)

your property file should look like.

message_en.properties

```
process_in_progress=Process is under prgress
process_failed=Process failed to execute.
```

Comment: It's called "i18n", not "i18th".

Comment: @BalusC Thanks , it was type, the reason behind i18n phenomena as I understood is there are 18 chars between internationalization i and n

Answer (score 0):

Several ways.

1. Use `rendered` attribute.

   ```
   <h:outputText value="Not processed" rendered="#{bean.status == 0}" />
   <h:outputText value="Being processed" rendered="#{bean.status == 1}" />
   <h:outputText value="Finished processing" rendered="#{bean.status == 2}" />
   ```
2. Use conditional operator `?:`  in EL.

   ```
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.status == 0 ? 'Not Processed' : bean.status == 1 ? 'Being processed' : 'Finished processing'}" />
   ```
3. Use an application-wide `Map<Integer, String>` somewhere.

   ```
   public class Bean {
       private static Map<Integer, String> statuses = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
       static {
           statuses.put(0, "Not processed");
           statuses.put(1, "Being processed");
           statuses.put(2, "Finished processing");
       }
       // Add getter.
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.statuses[bean.status]}" />
   ```

   which does basically `bean.getStatuses().get(bean.getStatus())`.